# How can you copy a node value from one data structure to another

Tags: c++

The specific task is that I have to copy the integer values from a binary tree and create a linked list with those values. The issue I am having is that when I traverse through the binary tree getting each integer at each node, I can't send the value of the node to the linked list allocation function

```
// Setting up the data structures:
struct node // node for the binary tree:
{
    int data; // variable to store each integer value in the tree
    node * left; // pointer for each right node
    node * right; // pointer for each left node
};
struct list_node // node for the linked list
{
    int list_data;
    list_node* next;
};

// Function for linked list insertion:
list_node * appendList(list_node *current, int newData)
{
    list_node *newNode = new list_node();
    newNode->list_data = newData;
    newNode->next = NULL; // now end of list
    current->next = newNode;
    return newNode;
}

void traverse(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    traverse(root->left); // first recursive
    // then send these values to the linked list
    //cout << root->data << " ";
    appendList(root, root->data);
    traverse(root->right); // second recusive
}
```

Error:

```
argument of type node is incompatible with parameter of type list_node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In below function call:
 appendList(root, root->data);

You are passing the incorrect first parameter i.e. root which is node of binary tree i.e. 'struct node' not 'struct list_node'.

**Solution:**
You have to pass the root of the list i.e. object 'struct list_node' as first parameter in function appendList.

**CHANGES**

struct list_node // node for the linked list
{
    int list_data;
    list_node* next;
};

// Function for linked list insertion:
list_node * appendList(list_node *root, int newData)
{
    list_node *newNode = new list_node();
    newNode->list_data = newData;
    newNode->next = NULL; // now end of list
    current->next = newNode;
    return newNode;
}

void traverse(node* root, list_node* rootList)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    traverse(root->left, rootList); // first recursive
    // then send these values to the linked list
    //cout << root->data << " ";
    rootList = appendList(rootList, root->data);
    traverse(root->right, rootList); // second recusive
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This call:

```
appendList(root, root->data);
```

Takes a `list_node` pointer, but you are giving it a `node` one.

In other words, you are trying to use the node of the binary tree as a list node, which is not really what you wanted to do. Try to use the root of the list structure, not the binary one.

Comment: Alright that shows me what direction to take. Also does that mean that I can't point to memory location that is already being pointed to. Eg: if node is pointing somewhere, node_list cannot point to it?

Comment: That is right. If you don't have a root node for the list, you will have to allocate one. Think of them as totally independent objects.